# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null - Local Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm creating a simple blog app that allows a user to create blog with a title and blog post. My app works 100% fine until I refresh and grab items that were stored in local storage. For Example, after I post a blog, I am able to click on the edit icon to make adjustments to the post and update it in the UI. As long as I do not refresh the page...this works 100% of the time. As soon as I refresh, my app looks perfectly fine and the blog posts previously added do show up from LS to my UI however, I can't click on the edit icon anymore and I get the "Cannot read property of.." error. I feel positive that I am using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse correctly. Fairly new to LS. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is how I am Storing my Items

```
storeItem: function (item) {
  let items;
  // Check if any items exist in LS 
  if (localStorage.getItem('items') === null) {
    items = [];
    // Push new item 
    items.push(item);
    // Set LS 
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
  } else {
    // Get existing items in LS 
    items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));

    // Push new item 
    items.push(item);

    // Reset LS 
    localStorage.setItem('items', JSON.stringify(items));
  }
},
```

And this is retrieving my items from LS

```
    getItemsFromStorage: function () {
  let items;
  if (localStorage.getItem('items') === null) {
    items = [];
  } else {
    items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items'));
  }
  return items;

}
```